# Binning DataFrame based on index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing

I have a Pandas dataframe with 150 rows and columns "A","B","C". I want to create column "D" that must have:

- 1 for 1-50 rows,
- 2 for 51-100 rows,
- 3 for 101-150 rows

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your dataframe index is a regular `pd.RangeIndex` (i.e. `0, 1, 2, ...`):

```
df['D'] = df.index // 50 + 1
```